# pyautogui throws me error message. How can I fix my code?

Tags: python, pyautogui

It gives me error message like below. How can I fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jayjeo\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 3, in <module>
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('yellow.png', confidence=0.8)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I made a code as below. I think that *if x.size == 0:* is the problem.

```
import pyautogui

x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('yellow.png', confidence=0.8)
if x.size == 0:
    print("Not Detected")
    pyautogui.click(1280,720)
else:
    print("Detected")
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

When I do print(x), I get the same error message.

Comment: `locateCenterOnScreen` returns two integers.  That's it.  There is no size.  Have you printed `x` and `y` to see what you got?  Did you, perhaps, want `locateOnScreen` instead?  That returns a `Box`.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback.

Comment: When I do "print(x)", I get the same error message. "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

Comment: The only tuple unpacking in this code is `x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen()`, and the docs say that function is guaranteed to either return a `(x, y)` tuple or raise an exception.  So I don't understand how it would return None as the error says.

Comment: @TimRoberts I need "locateCenterOnScreen" to click an object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was changed in version 0.9.41.  After that point, if the window is not found, it raises an exception.  Before that point, it returns `None`.  So, you need:

```
pt = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('yellow.png', confidence=0.8)
if not pt:
    print("Not Detected")
    pyautogui.click(1280,720)
else:
    x, y = pt
    print("Detected")
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

If you upgrade, you will have to add exception handling for this case.